# How to integrate a Satchmo store inside an existing django project?

Tags: django, django-templates, satchmo

I'm working with a Satchmo store installation that should reside within an existing django project. This django project has its own settings.py, local_settings.py, templates as well as templates for some of the various apps that have been installed.

Can you please suggest the steps to integrate satchmo store inside an existing django project with satchmo store using the django projects settings.py, local_settings.py, templates and database?

Comment: In other words, I'm trying to fix Satchmo so that it can be integrated in any Django
project as an app and customize it.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to do something similar. But it depends on what you want to actually do. I presume the most valuable part of Satchmo is the payment processing. It was for us. A cart with products and inventory is actually pretty simple to pull off with django. Satchmo was pulled apart into separate apps, and the payment processing was made into django-bursar (https://bitbucket.org/bkroeze/django-bursar) (I along with others have forked it to add some functionality).

Taking that app and connecting to gateways for payment processing is fairly straightforward.

Comment: John, I'm trying to use the satchmo store as a whole rather than pulling the apps used in satchmo apart and using them seperately. Any ideas?

Comment: setting it up as a separate app within your project should work just fine. it has its own whole structure. again - i don't know what you're actually trying to do. if you just want the store up and running on its own. it shouldn't be that bad.